# How to store an ssl key as a variable in a script for use with ncat?

Tags: bash, ssl, environment-variables

I am trying to write a wrapper script to start an ncat listener. I don't want to have to output the certificate and key to a file, rather I'd like to store it as a variable within the script, and call it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

crt="(           ---BEGIN CERT ----
MIICjdkfj4544757jkdfjdkfjsfsdkljf4alwjkqe3r3lkfd
dfjsdkfjdkfjdkfjdf34534235jeklgjeg94gjriogjgojdgkdo7HH
87HSKRNSSFSDFJDKDJFKJDSF/7387dfddffdfd8jhrg8hgs....etc")

ncat --listen --ssl --ssl-cert "$crt" --ssl-key "$key" 127.0.0.1 4444
```

But ncat (or bash) keep interpretting the key as a super long  file name, rather than the key itself. Basically I want to store the key and cert as variables, and have ncat read them as if it was reading it from an actual file. Is this possible? I've tried several different methods, and have had no luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
ncat --listen --ssl --ssl-cert <(echo -n "$crt") --ssl-key <(echo -n "$key") 127.0.0.1 4444
```

The `-n` is there so that `echo` doesn't add a newline.  The `<( ... )` is called process substitution in Bash and it essentially creates a virtual file from a command.  It lets you use pretty much anything that can generate a stream of bytes with most any program that reads a stream of bytes from a file path.

Some programs won't work with this because they try to do things a stream doesn't support, like seek.  But most programs will simply read the file into an internal buffer, and with these programs, process substitution will let you do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The man page of ncat says

```
--ssl-cert             Specify SSL certificate file (PEM) for listening
```

You are specifying a file path with --ssl-cert. You could write the cert string to a file and use that file as the argument to -ssl-cert instead.

```
crt="--BEGIN CERT-- ..."
echo $crt > cirt.tmp
ncat --ssl-cert cirt.tmp ...
```

Sorry, I just noticed that you said you didn't want to use a file. You could delete the file after writing to it, if it helps.

Comment: Yeah, I want to keep it it memory by reading it from a variable rather than outputting it to a file.

Comment: Why is that, may I ask? Is it because you are worried about the security of the file? You could set the permissions of the file to be not world or group readable/writeable.

Comment: Well, first, I just really want to know how to do it. Second, one of the servers I'd like to use it on is in a shared user environment, where anyone with half a brain and a webshell can read everybody's everything, and we only have ftp access (only 10 users can be logged in at time... lame), so this is my solution. Not that they couldn't get the key from the single file, but its easier for me to hide/obfuscate/contain  everything I need in a shell script with some openssl encrpytion, a password, handled by `expect`. So I feel like the less files I have to leave  around, the better.

Comment: It looks like ncat does not support your use case. The -ssl-cert passes its value directly to the openssl function SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file, which reads from a file. Another option for you is to write the value to a named pipe with mkfifo, then use the mkfifo filename as the argument to --ssl-cert. I haven't tried it myself, though.

Comment: That sounds interesting... has anyone ever done something like that?